# onClickListener crashing application and onOptionsItemSelected not triggering as intended

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener

I'm trying to create a basic rating application with an embedded database. Unfortunately though, whenever I try to program an onClickListener to my reportSomeoneButton, the application crashes or the event isn't called upon correctly and the button does nothing.

What the intended action is, is for someone to click the reportSomeoneButton, this creates an alert dialog asking for user input. The user inputs the comment, and then the information is stored in a database and populates the table below.

I've been struggling for many hours with this now. Tutorials aren't hitting on what I'm looking for, other questions on stackoverflow are helpful in learning different things, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this. I'm very new to developing with Android Studio, so any kind of assistance would be greatly appreciated, whether it's a perfect solution or just pointing me in the right direction with my research, all will be appreciated!

Anyways, here's what I have:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

import static android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Welcome!";

    //private Reports currentReport;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    tools:context="com.example.feral.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/honkhonklogo" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**DisplayMessageActivity.java**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    public String currentDate;
    private RatingDBHelper dbAssistant;
    private ListView listHandler;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayHandler;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private TextView getCurrentDate;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Welcome, " + message + "!");
        getCurrentDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        getCurrentDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                //int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        DisplayMessageActivity.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        dateListener,
                        year, month, day);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFFFF6666));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        dateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day)
            {
                month = month + 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyyy: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

                String submittedDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
                if (!(submittedDate != null && !submittedDate.isEmpty()))
                {
                    currentDate = submittedDate;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentDate = submittedDate;
                }
                getCurrentDate.setText(submittedDate);
            }
        };
          dbAssistant = new RatingDBHelper(this);
          listHandler = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.reportedRatings);
          refreshList();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.reportSomeoneButton:
                final EditText reportInput = new EditText(this);
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Report a Driver")
                        .setMessage("License Plate #: ")
                        .setView(reportInput)
                        .setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i)
                            {
                                String licensePlate = String.valueOf(reportInput.getText());
                                SQLiteDatabase db = dbAssistant.getWritableDatabase();
                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                values.put(ReportDataSource.ReportSubmission.COL_TASK_TITLE, licensePlate + "\n" + currentDate);
                                db.insertWithOnConflict(ReportDataSource.ReportSubmission.TABLE,
                                        null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                                db.close();
                                refreshList();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .create();
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void refreshList()
    {
        ArrayList<String> reportList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbAssistant.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(ReportDataSource.ReportSubmission.TABLE,
                new String[] {ReportDataSource.ReportSubmission._ID, ReportDataSource.ReportSubmission.COL_TASK_TITLE},
                null, null, null, null,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ReportDataSource.ReportSubmission.COL_TASK_TITLE);
            reportList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
        }

        if(arrayHandler == null)
        {
            arrayHandler = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            R.layout.activity_display_message,
            R.id.textView,
            reportList);
            listHandler.setAdapter(arrayHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            arrayHandler.clear();
            arrayHandler.addAll(reportList);
            arrayHandler.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

**activity_display_message.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.feral.myapplication.DisplayMessageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reportSomeoneButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/reportSomeone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ratingBar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blankprofile" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/reportedRatings"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="339dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reportSomeoneButton" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I also have the DBHelper, Database Source code files, but I do not believe they're relevant to this issue.

Again, thank you all for any help!

Comment: you might want to post your crash log. it'll be easier for others to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, initialize your reportedSomeButton inside OnCreate().Instead of calling inside OnOptionsItemSelected(..), try this inside onCreate().

```
reportSomeoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Report a Driver")
                    .setMessage("License Plate #: ")
                    .setView(reportInput)
                    .setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i)
                        {
                            String licensePlate = String.valueOf(reportInput.getText());
                            SQLiteDatabase db = dbAssistant.getWritableDatabase();
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put(ReportDataSource.ReportSubmission.COL_TASK_TITLE, licensePlate + "\n" + currentDate);
                            db.insertWithOnConflict(ReportDataSource.ReportSubmission.TABLE,
                                    null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                            db.close();
                            refreshList();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
            }



    });
```

Hope this may help you.